# Making schema changes in production environment with Sequelize with no data loss

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) as my ORM for a PostgreSQL database, and need some pointers on making schema changes in production without data loss:

```
// model usage
var User = require('./user')
var Page = require('./page')
var Theme = require('./theme')

User.sync({
    force: true
})

Page.sync({
    force: true
})

Theme.sync({
    force: true
})
```

In development, I have data loss each time I restart my API server because I have `force: true`. This is manageable, because it's development.
But I obviously don't want this for my production environment, but how do I get around this issue:

1. I have a user's schema: name, age, etc...
2. A user signs up
3. I then decide I'd also like to capture "email" and save it in the User's table.
4. Column "email" not found, because `force: false` in production

How do I go about making sure my production schema is up to date? And that I can make these schema changes without data loss?

I come from the Mongo world where this just isn't an issue, any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL world, Migrations are the way to go.
You'll need to write a migration to add email column in your table.

If you are using Sequelize >= 2.0.0 , then you use it's own migrations library: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/